# How to open a a file:line:col that works with tabs?

Tags: emacsclient

Currently I'm using:

```
emacsclient +12:34 some_file.txt
```

This works for the line but not for the column, since tabs are expanded when calculating the offset.

Is there a way to open a file at the correct column based on the character offset instead of white space width?

Answer (score 2):

Posting own answer which works but is a little clumsy.

```
emacsclient --eval \
  "(progn (find-file \\"some_file.txt\\") (goto-line 12) (forward-char 34) (recenter))" \
  --no-wait \
  --alternate-editor="emacs --eval"
```